# Is Modernizr becoming increasingly obsolete?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, modernizr

Is it worth to start learning how to make use of Modernizr if one has no intention to support IE8 anymore?

Will Modernizr become obsolete in the near future because of increasing support of (most) HTML5 elements / CSS3 ?

Comment: Modernizr is just a small library with some methods, what you need to learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New browser features are always being released, so there will always be a use case for feature detection.

The only things which *might* eventually make Modernizr obsolete are native feature detection APIs, like [`CSS.supports()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS.supports) and [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports), but only if they (a) gain enough browser support and (b) prove to be reliable enough.

The problem with *native* feature detection APIs is they rely on the browser vendors to “tell the truth”… a browser may claim it supports a particular feature, but it may be an incomplete or buggy implementation, or even missing altogether.

Modernizr already acts to “smooth over the gaps” in these cases, by using more detailed detection techniques or blacklisting certain browsers, for cases where browsers are known to have poor implementations. It’s likely to keep this role for some time to come.

We’d actually love for Modernizr to no longer be needed. It’s a burden having to include it in your pages and impacts page load performance (although we do our best to keep it as fast as possible). But that doesn’t look like it’s going to happen any time soon.

But not everyone needs it. You certainly shouldn’t include it if you don’t actually need to.